# How do I disable Chromium icon in system tray in XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, chromium, 20.04, xfce-panel

**OS:** Xubuntu 20.04

**DE:** XFCE 4.14

**Package:** Chromium 81.0.4044.129

How can I disable the Chromium icon in the system tray? It appears the first time I open Chromium, and remains until I shut down the PC, even if I close Chromium. It does not appear to provide any function; clicking on it does nothing with or without Chromium running.

[image: Screenshot of Chromium icon in task bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Launch Chromium.
2. Go to *Settings* > *Advanced* > *System* (or simply type `chrome://settings/system` in the address bar).
3. Toggle the '*Continue running background apps when Chromium is closed*' option off.